# Domino's Advertising Pizza Claim

Tags: probability-theory, soft-question, statistical-inference

I just got a Dominos promotional flier through the post and one of the graphics advertising 'create your own pizza' lists the various toppings and claims there are 'more combinations than people in the world'

There are 19 toppings available, I am interested to know how you work it out.

Comment: Well 2^19 = 524288 which is less than the number of people in the world, this isn't true using toppings alone.  But perhaps they also count dividing the toppings into different halves, and different sizes of pizza, etc.

Comment: Are double and triple toppings allowed? That could also change the answer here.

Comment: If no multiple toppings allowed, there would need 33 different topping to have more possibilities than people in the world

Comment: Perhaps Dominos saw this blog posting:  http://gottwurfelt.com/2013/08/03/34-million-pizzas-is-a-massive-understatement/

Comment: If you can choose what toppings to put on each half of the pizza (so for each topping, it can be on the whole pizza, only the left half, only the right half, or not at all), and you have $4^{19}$ possibilities, which is about $270$ billion. Some of those are redundant (if the pizzas are mirror images), but probably still puts us over the $6$ billion or so we need.

Comment: What kind of promotion is that??? How does having billions of different possible combinations make a pizza any better if you can only eat, say, $10000$ regular-size pizzas throughout an average life-span of $80$ years? (you could try to double that, but it still wouldn't even cover the population of a small town, let alone the fact that you will probably die of a cardiac failure long before you reach $80$).

Comment: Maybe everyone wants a pizza that nobody else has ever had ;)

Comment: I believe that @BaronVT was on the right track considering the option to choose each half of the pizza

Answer (score 3):

For each topping, you can either include it or not, so
$$
2^{19}=524,288
$$
which is considerably less than the population of the world.

Answer (score 1):

There are 19 toppings and 4 different crusts, HOWEVER you are also allowed pizzas where you choose each half. Therefore its,

$$2^{19}\times 4 + {2^{19}\times 4 \choose 2}$$

I would guess this is larger than 7 billion.